# How to traverse a json in laravel with blade?

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have this in the backend

```
return view('changePrice')->with('list',$list);
```

And my page has

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 {!! json_encode($list) !!}
</body>
</html>
```

And I can see on my page something like

```
[{"id":"10e408ab-b768-6c84-9793-588a440e8b71","name":"Cambio Precio","lista":"OVG","oficina_ventas":"1300","lista_precios":"14","tipo_precio":"LISTA","nit":"","producto":"209","material":"LANGOSTINO 16-20","unidad_medida":"KG","precio_actual":"62900.000000","nuevo_precio":"67300.000000","fecha_inicio":"2017-01-16","procesado":"0"},,{"id":"111b95da-bde7-3c2f-0a92-588a44f6022f","name":"Cambio Precio","lista":"OVG","oficina_ventas":"1100","lista_precios":"17","tipo_precio":"LISTA","nit":"","producto":"274","material":"CAMARON GOLDEN CRUDO - RAW PD 51-60","unidad_medida":"KG","precio_actual":"36500.000000","nuevo_precio":"37500.000000","fecha_inicio":"2017-01-16","procesado":"0"}
```

I do not know much about blade, but,How to tap this json?To create a table

Comment: whats the problem you are facing, if you have problem with json stuff, use normal array and traverse in the blade.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show all data then you can get easily in view page.

```
{{print_r($list)}}
```

Otherwise you can use @foreach

Please see example here.

```
<table>
@foreach($list as $value)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $value->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to turn a perfectly good array/collection into JSON here. Just work on the PHP `$list` directly, using a `@foreach` loop in Blade:

```
<table>
    @foreach($list as $item)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

I'd strongly encourage you to [consult the Blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade) for more examples of this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks,but i have a error: 
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @SebastianMoncada Can you share the *rest* of that error message?

Comment: Thanks, it already gave.
I add:
{{$item["id"]}}
and it worked

Comment: Answer is less relevant. Question was asking to traverse a Json data.